# Login to subdomain from main website

Tags: authentication, asp.net-mvc-5, single-sign-on

I'm trying to implement SSO for my two MVC application. The main Application is Beno.biz and the second is task.beno.biz
I need when user log in in beno.biz be able to access Authorized views in task.beno.biz.
My codes :
beno.biz - web.config

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" 
         name=".BENOAUTH"
         cookieless="UseCookies"
         domain=".beno.biz"
         path="/"
         protection="All"
         requireSSL="false"
         enableCrossAppRedirects="true" />
    </authentication>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    </httpModules>
    <machineKey validationKey="E4451576F51E0562D91A1748DF7AB3027FEF3C2CCAC46D756C833E1AF20C7BAEFFACF97C7081ADA4648918E0B56BF27D1699A6EB2D9B6967A562CAD14767F163"
   decryptionKey="6159C46C9E288028ED26F5A65CED7317A83CB3485DE8C592" validation="HMACSHA256" decryption="AES" />
</system.web>
```

Beno.biz => Account Controller

```
[AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login(string fromsite, string returnUrl)
    {
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fromsite))
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl =fromsite  + returnUrl;
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/Login
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
        // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                {
                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                }
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password");
                return View(model);
        }
    }
```

Beno.biz => Startup.Auth

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            CookieDomain = ".beno.biz",
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
                // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            }
        });
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);


        app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));

        app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);

    }
}
```

these codes all are in the main website which name is beno.biz, after this codes I've been added some configuration in my subdomain project which name is task.beno.biz.

task.beno.biz => web.config

```
<system.web>
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name=".BENOAUTH" loginUrl="http://beno.biz/Account/Login?fromsite=http://www.task.beno.biz" cookieless="UseCookies" domain=".beno.biz" path="/" protection="All" requireSSL="false" enableCrossAppRedirects="true" />
</authentication>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" />
<httpModules>
  <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
</httpModules>
<machineKey validationKey="E4451576F51E0562D91A1748DF7AB3027FEF3C2CCAC46D756C833E1AF20C7BAEFFACF97C7081ADA4648918E0B56BF27D1699A6EB2D9B6967A562CAD14767F163" decryptionKey="6159C46C9E288028ED26F5A65CED7317A83CB3485DE8C592" validation="HMACSHA256" decryption="AES" />
```

and then I addes some codes into Startup.Auth of task.beno.biz

task.beno.biz => Startup.Auth

```
public partial class Startup
{
    // For more information on configuring authentication, please visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301864
    public void ConfigureAuth(AppBuilder app)
    {
        // Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
        //app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        //app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        //app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

        // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
        // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
        // Configure the sign in cookie
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            CookieDomain = ".beno.biz",
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,

        });
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        // Enables the application to temporarily store user information when they are verifying the second factor in the two-factor authentication process.
        app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));

        app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);

    }
}
```

my subdomain does not recognize logged in user, do I need more configuration and settings?